# android listview itemclick issue

Tags: android, image, listview

Hello my name it Nathan and I have problem with my code, I wanted to ask for your help. If you could help me it I would appreciate it a lot.
I have a listview that is populated by a database.  My  target was to select few of the items on the listview and next to those listviews there will be a "check" image . But my problem is as you can see down below is that when I click on one item the "check" image appears also on another item.
Here's my code if that could help you

```
package com.example.lamder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GetActivity extends Activity {
    RegistrationAdapter adapter_ob;
    RegistrationOpenHelper helper_ob;
    SQLiteDatabase db_ob;
    ListView nameList;
    Button registerBtn;
    Cursor cursor;
    static boolean[] check=new boolean[100];
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.getact);
        nameList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_name);
        registerBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
        adapter_ob = new RegistrationAdapter(this);
        cursor=adapter_ob.queryName();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text =getString(R.string.selectby);
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
        for(int i=0;i<check.length;i++)
            check[i]=false;
        String[] from = { helper_ob.FNAME, helper_ob.LNAME };   

        int[] to = { R.id.tv_fname, R.id.tv_lname };
        cursor = adapter_ob.queryName();
        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
        nameList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        nameList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {       
                ImageView img=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                if(check[position]==false)
                {
                    check[position]=true;
                    img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                     check[position]=false;
                     img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   
                }


            }
        });
```

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/backnote" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_fname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:text="ans" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tv_lname"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_fname" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/blackbar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_lname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_fname"
            android:text="ques" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_lname" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:src="@drawable/checker"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
            --that's the picture i want to make visible when clicked
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope you could help me, thanks, Nathan

Answer (score 0):

You should try example like that : http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

The problem here is that the item that is checked is reused when you scroll on the list, therefore it remains checked (but for items with other name) if you don't have a list/array with the actual state of each checkbox.